# COUNT returns the number of all rows even the one excluded with except

Tags: sql, cs50

I am trying write a sql query  where the desired output is 176 lines

Here is the query:

```
SELECT name FROM people WHERE id IN(SELECT person_id FROM stars WHERE movie_id IN (SELECT id FROM movies WHERE id IN ( SELECT movie_id FROM stars WHERE person_id = (SELECT id FROM people WHERE birth = 1958 AND name = 'Kevin Bacon'))))EXCEPT SELECT name FROM people WHERE name = "Kevin Bacon";
```

I am getting the correct output, but when I check the code to count the number of rows (I substitute name with COUNT(name)) COUNT returns 177, because it's not excluding the rows in the EXCEPT statement.

Is there any way to make count consider the EXCEPT statement???
Here is some more info:

This is the problem set
https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/7/movies/
I'm stuck on 13.sql

.schema returns

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
                    id INTEGER,
                    title TEXT NOT NULL,
                    year NUMERIC,
                    PRIMARY KEY(id)
                );
CREATE TABLE stars (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE directors (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE ratings (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                rating REAL NOT NULL,
                votes INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE people (
                id INTEGER,
                name TEXT NOT NULL,
                birth NUMERIC,
                PRIMARY KEY(id)
            );
```

Comment: Obviously, you are trying to do something.  Obviously, your query is not doing it.  It is entirely not obvious what you want to do or what your data looks like.

Comment: Why not use an ordinary WHERE instead of EXCEPT? Also if the left query returns a number and the right a string what would be excepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an except to work the arguments on both sides of the EXCEPT must be the same. The best way to get a count in this instant is to wrap the entire query to get a derived table so the name 'Kevin Bacon' can be 'excepted' and then ask for the count from that derived table.

```
Select count(1)
From (
SELECT name FROM people 
WHERE id IN(SELECT person_id FROM stars 
WHERE movie_id IN (SELECT id FROM movies
WHERE id IN ( SELECT movie_id FROM stars 
WHERE person_id = (SELECT id FROM people 
WHERE birth = 1958 AND name = 'Kevin Bacon'))))
EXCEPT SELECT name FROM people WHERE name = 'Kevin Bacon'
) as A
```